# Does JavaScript have an indexOf(lambda) or similar?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, optimization

I want to return the index of the first element satisfying a unary predicate.

Example:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7].indexOf((x) => x % 3 === 0) // returns 2
```

Is there such a function? The alternative I was going to use was

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7].reduce((retval,curelem,idx) => 
{
   if(curelem % 3 === 0 && retval === undefined)
       retval = idx; 
   return retval;
}, undefined);
```

but of course that would be less efficient since it doesn't stop iterating through the array after it has found the element.

Comment: [Array.prototype.findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)

Comment: @Vohuman post it as an answer (with an example and couple more words) and I'll upvote you

Answer (score 35):

Yes, there is such function: [`Array.prototype.findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex). The method was introduced by ECMAScript 2015 and you need to use a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex#Polyfill) for supporting older browsers.

Comment: "and it works just like the lambd function" --- this statement looks weird.

Comment: Well, I cannot think of what it means actually. I don't know that it means for something "to work like the lambda function". To me (since the standard does not provide an official definition for that), a lambda function === a function expression.

Answer (score 15):

yes it exists :

```
console.log([1,2,3,4,5,6,7].findIndex((x) => x % 3 === 0));
```